# How to increase fetching speed of large data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Following is my query which takes 2:26 minutes for fetching 9'619'516 records from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Query:

```
SELECT 
    SERVERID, MSGID, BPID, FLOWID, FSID, FSSTEP, 
    MESSAGETYPEID, MESSAGESTRING, USERBLOB, USERCODE, 
    CREATEDATE, CREATETIME, OBJECTLEVEL, CATEGORY, 
    USERKEY1, USERKEY2, VERSIONKEY, STATUSCODE, SEVERITY, 
    EXTENSION, PROJECTKEY, BLOBEXISTS, ROOTFSID, 
    FLOWREQUESTID, FILELOCATION, RUNID, 
    TEMP_MGXPI4_1.DateTimeObject, TEMP_MGXPI4_1.TEMP_ROW_NUM 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         SERVERID, MSGID, BPID, FLOWID, FSID, FSSTEP, 
         MESSAGETYPEID, MESSAGESTRING, USERBLOB, USERCODE, 
         CREATEDATE, CREATETIME, OBJECTLEVEL, CATEGORY, 
         USERKEY1, USERKEY2, VERSIONKEY, STATUSCODE, 
         SEVERITY, EXTENSION, PROJECTKEY, BLOBEXISTS, ROOTFSID, 
         FLOWREQUESTID, FILELOCATION, RUNID,
         REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CREATEDATE, 126),'-','') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),CREATETIME) AS DateTimeObject,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CREATEDATE DESC, CREATETIME DESC, MSGID DESC) AS TEMP_ROW_NUM 
     FROM 
         IFS_ACTLOG 
     WHERE 
         PROJECTKEY = 'Project1' AND ROOTFSID = 1) AS TEMP_MGXPI4_1
```

SQL Server execution plan of query:

[image: Execution plan of query]

Comment: And what will you do with your 9.5 million records? I like to load lower orders of magnitude like that into a combo box so the user can browse and pick one for a more detailed analysis..

Comment: Why do you bother with the subquery? This single table-using-index select is so simple it doesn't appear to warrant writing your query in such a relatively complex way. Formatting that datetime into a string 9.5million times will bulk the response data up by a needless number of megabytes. You don't appear to use the row number you generate either, so that seems a waste of resources

Comment: There are typically two ways to reduce execution time: **(1)** load really **only** those columns you absolutely need - this might even allow you to skip that very expensive "Key Lookup" operation - and **(2)** load only the **rows** that you need by providing a sensible set of `WHERE` conditions. Loading over 9.5 million rows seems excessive .....

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning the infrastructure and use case between this database and the consuming client.. If it's a mobile app on a 3G connection streaming all this data out of a database with 1milion concurrent users, 2.5minutes would actually be an awesome result.. Context. Context. Context

Comment: @Caius Jard,we have monitoring tool where we need to show these details on dashboard for monitorng purpose for e.g perticular ROOTFSID =1, So is there any way we can optimize this query or do we need to have paging in query? like for e.g 100/200 records per page.

Comment: No-one needs to show 9.5 million records on a monitor. There aren't even 9.5 million pixels on a 4K monitor, so unless you're doing some funky sub-pixel visualization using different colors of individual pixels to represent different aspects in the data set, you've got a fundamental design flaw. Summarize your data so the database does more than simply spend most of its life serving the contents of its MDF over a network connection

Comment: This looks, to me, like a query dynamically generated by some intervening layer which is not sufficiently smart to understand the derived table has no real use/advantage here. Which leads me to think that you focus on the wrong problem. Apparently magic software needs a lot more magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood, your  performance is based on moving large quantities of data.

But, from a performance perspective, your query is:

```
SELECT . . .,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CREATEDATE DESC, CREATETIME DESC, MSGID DESC) AS TEMP_ROW_NUM 
 FROM  IFS_ACTLOG 
 WHERE PROJECTKEY = 'Project1' AND ROOTFSID = 1
```

This query suggests an index on `(PROJECTKEY, ROOTFSID, CREATEDATE DESC, CREATETIME DESC, MSGID)`.

That said, even if the query runs faster, the volume of data being moved outside the database will still take time to process.